# Check multiple Boolean condition in java

Tags: java

I have a scenario in which I have to check whether the template exists already in the database. If it exists I have to return a message based on the existing template.

I have several templates: Email, Letter, SMS. If all of them exist I have to return "All template exist already."

If only the Email template exists I have to return that only the email template exists, same for Letter and Sms templates.

Code:

```
for (EventVO eventVO: eventModuleList) {
    List <EmailTemplateMaster> emailTemplateList = communicationDAO
        .checkEmailTemplateExist(eventVO.getEventCode());
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(emailTemplateList)) {
        emailTemplateExist = true;
    }
    List <LetterTemplateMaster> letterTemplateList = communicationDAO
        .checkLetterTemplateExist(eventVO.getEventCode());
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(letterTemplateList)) {
        letterTemplateExist = true;
    }
    List <SmsTemplateMaster> smsTemplateList = communicationDAO
        .checkSmsTemplateExist(eventVO.getEventCode());
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(smsTemplateList)) {
        smsTemplateExist = true;
    }
    if (emailTemplateExist && letterTemplateExist && smsTemplateExist) {
        templateExist = CommunicationConstants.ALL_TEMPLATE_EXIST;
    }
    if (emailTemplateExist || !letterTemplateExist && !smsTemplateExist) {
        templateExist = CommunicationConstants.EMAIL_TEMPLATE_EXIST;
    }
    if (!emailTemplateExist && letterTemplateExist && !smsTemplateExist) {
        templateExist = CommunicationConstants.LETTER_TEMPLATE_EXIST;
    }
    if (!emailTemplateExist && !letterTemplateExist && smsTemplateExist) {
        templateExist = CommunicationConstants.SMS_TEMPLATE_EXIST;
    }
}
```

Can I know the easiest way to check the Boolean value of exit template exist.

Based on exit, I have to sent the corresponding message.

```
public static final String ALL_TEMPLATE_EXIST = "Email, Letter and Sms Template already exist for the selected event."; 
public static final String EMAIL_TEMPLATE_EXIST = "Email Template already exist for the selected event.";
public static final String SMS_TEMPLATE_EXIST = "Sms Template already exist for the selected event.";
public static final String LETTER_TEMPLATE_EXIST = "Email Letter Template already exist for the selected event.";
public static final String EMAIL_SMS_TEMPLATE_EXIST = "Email and Sms Template already exist for the selected event.";
public static final String EMAIL_LETTER_TEMPLATE_EXIST = "Email and Letter Template already exist for the selected event.";
public static final String SMS_LETTER_TEMPLATE_EXIST = "Sms and Letter Template already exist for the selected event.";
```

Comment: you'll need to learn about the else block and the ! operator

Comment: Are you sure you want to skipt the cases of no template existing or two of three of them existing? You only check the cases in which two templates are not existing...

Comment: I not able to arrive a decision to fix this. Above I pasted is sample code I tried. Sorry for confusion

Comment: Can you show what these functions like checkLetterTemplateExist, checkLetterTemplateExist etc does? Based on that perhaps you can go with Enum.

Answer (score 3):

You could "prepare" the mapping between the booleans and the messages in the `CommunicationConstants` class:

```
public class CommunicationConstants
{
    private static final Map<List<Boolean>, String> CONSTANTS = new HashMap<>();
    static
    {
        CONSTANTS.put(Arrays.asList(true, true, true), "Email, Letter and Sms Template already exist for the selected event.");
        CONSTANTS.put(Arrays.asList(true, true, false), "Email and Sms Template already exist for the selected event.");
        CONSTANTS.put(Arrays.asList(true, false, true), "Email and Letter Template already exist for the selected event.");
        CONSTANTS.put(Arrays.asList(false, true, true), "Sms and Letter Template already exist for the selected event.");
        CONSTANTS.put(Arrays.asList(true, false, false), "Email Template already exist for the selected event.");
        CONSTANTS.put(Arrays.asList(false, true, false), "Sms Template already exist for the selected event.");
        CONSTANTS.put(Arrays.asList(false, false, true), "Letter Template already exist for the selected event.");
    }

    public static String getMessage(boolean emailExists, boolean smsExists, boolean letterExists)
    {
        return CONSTANTS.get(Arrays.asList(emailExists, smsExists, letterExists));
    }
}
```

The code to retrieve it will be a one-liner then:

```
System.out.println(CommunicationConstants.getMessage(true, false, true));
```

Comment: You will need to add scenario where all vales in list are `false` as well

Comment: @NicholasK After posting the answer I saw it mentioned in some comment and thought about adding it. It wasn't listed in Op's code, though, and I thought returning null isn't the worst choice. But sure, you could easily add that case to the map.

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible to you to change your DataBase model, do following changes:

1- Change all booleans into Template type which is VARCHAR() with following allowed values => ALL_TEMPLATE_EXIST, EMAIL_TEMPLATE_EXIST, LETTER_TEMPLATE_EXIST, SMS_TEMPLATE_EXIST

2- After reading the value from data base use only one line code to set your values:

`templateExist = CommunicationConstants.valueOf(thePropertyValueYouReadFromDataBase);`

***Edit***

By this change, taking decision of which template already exist would be up to the business code which insert template, reading part only read value of what really inserted

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way. I find it clearer but obviously every body's mind is different.

```
if (emailTemplateExist) {
    templateExist = letterTemplateExist && smsTemplateExist ? CommunicationConstants.ALL_TEMPLATE_EXIST: CommunicationConstants.EMAIL_TEMPLATE_EXIST;
}
else{
    if (letterTemplateExist && !smsTemplateExist)
        templateExist = CommunicationConstants.LETTER_TEMPLATE_EXIST;
    else if (!letterTemplateExist && smsTemplateExist)
        templateExist = CommunicationConstants.SMS_TEMPLATE_EXIST;
}

// There is a possiblity that you will end up with a null value in templateExist so you should initialize it with some default.
```

Comment: Your code doesn't manage these three cases: email-sms, email-letter, sms-letter

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you are missing several cases… However, you can do it by nesting `if` statements. Please note that I added a value to the `enum` that represents the case of no template existing in the database. With this approach, you will need additional `enum` values for *email and sms*, *email and letter* and *letter and sms*. If you are sure those cases will never happen, then this approach covers too much.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean emailTemplateExist = true;
    boolean letterTemplateExist = true;
    boolean smsTemplateExist = true;

    CommunicationConstants templateExist = CommunicationConstants.NO_TEMPLATE_EXIST;

    if (emailTemplateExist) {
        if (letterTemplateExist) {
            if (smsTemplateExist) {
                // email exists, letter exists, sms exists ==> 3/3
                templateExist = CommunicationConstants.ALL_TEMPLATE_EXIST;
            } else {
                // email exists, letter exists, sms does not exist ==> 2/3
                // what to do here?

                /*
                 *  what to do in this case? The enum has no value for that...
                 */
            }
        } else {
            if (smsTemplateExist) {
                // email exists, letter does not exist, sms exists ==> 2/3

                /*
                 *  what to do in this case? The enum has no value for that...
                 */
            } else {
                // email exists, letter does not exist, sms does not exist ==> 1/3

            }
        }
    } else {
        if (letterTemplateExist) {
            if (smsTemplateExist) {
                // email does not exist, letter exists, sms exists ==> 2/3

                /*
                 *  what to do in this case? The enum has no value for that...
                 */
            } else {
                // email does not exist, letter exists, sms does not exist ==> 1/3
                templateExist = CommunicationConstants.LETTER_TEMPLATE_EXIST;
            }
        } else {
            if (smsTemplateExist) {
                // email does not exist, letter does not exist, sms exists ==> 1/3
                templateExist = CommunicationConstants.SMS_TEMPLATE_EXIST;
            } else {
                // email does not exist, letter does not exist, sms does not exist ==> 0/3

                /* 
                 * by initializing the return value with something like "NO_TEMPLATE_EXIST",
                 * you can omit this else block entirely
                 */
                templateExist = CommunicationConstants.NO_TEMPLATE_EXIST;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(templateExist.toString());

}

enum CommunicationConstants {
    ALL_TEMPLATE_EXIST,
    EMAIL_TEMPLATE_EXIST,
    LETTER_TEMPLATE_EXIST,
    SMS_TEMPLATE_EXIST,
    NO_TEMPLATE_EXIST
}
```

Just play around with the initial values (currently, they all are `true`).

Answer (score 0):

Below code generates all combinations with single template:

```
public class Main {

    enum TemplateType {
        Email, Sms, Letter
    }

    private static final String MSG_EXISTS = "%s Template%s already exist%s for the selected event.";
    private static int testCounter;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Generates all combinations
        for (testCounter = 0; testCounter < 8; testCounter++) {
            System.out.println(testCounter + ". " + evaluate());
        }
    }

    private static String evaluate() {

        List<String> templateList = Arrays.stream(TemplateType.values())
                .filter(Main::checkExistence)
                .map(TemplateType::name)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        if (templateList.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        int size = templateList.size();
        String arg1 = prettyPrintListJoiner(templateList);

        return String.format(MSG_EXISTS, arg1, size == 1 ? "" : "s", size == 1 ? "s" : "");
    }

    private static String prettyPrintListJoiner(List<String> templateList) {

        int size = templateList.size();
        if (size == 1) {
            return templateList.get(0);
        }

        StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(", ");
        if (size > 2) {
            joiner.add(String.join(", ", templateList.subList(0, size - 2)));
        }
        return joiner.add(String.join(" and ", templateList.subList(size - 2, size))).toString();
    }

    // To generate all possibilities with help of testCounter
    private static boolean checkExistence(TemplateType type) {
        switch (type) {
            case Email:
                return ((testCounter >> 2) & 1) == 1;
            case Sms:
                return ((testCounter >> 1) & 1) == 1;
            case Letter:
                return ((testCounter) & 1) == 1;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Test Output:

```
0. null
1. Letter Template already exists for the selected event.
2. Sms Template already exists for the selected event.
3. Sms and Letter Templates already exist for the selected event.
4. Email Template already exists for the selected event.
5. Email and Letter Templates already exist for the selected event.
6. Email and Sms Templates already exist for the selected event.
7. Email, Sms and Letter Templates already exist for the selected event.
```